# SQL query optimization

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query that takes too long to execute.
I need to know if there is any optimum way of executing that to reduce execution time.

my query is

```
SELECT     TOP (2) ID,
                   (
                    SELECT     SUM(CurrentStock) AS SimilarItemQuantity
                    FROM          Inventory AS T1
                    WHERE      (Inventory.ProductName = ProductName)
                   ) 
                   AS Expr1
FROM         Inventory
```

Consider that for 20 records and it takes 15 seconds.
Is there a more faster way of doing it.

Comment: What DBMS are you using?  What indexes do you have on the `Inventory` table?  Have you looked at the execution plan?

Comment: is `Inventory.ProductName` indexed ?

Comment: Its SQLSERVER and no inventory table is not indexed.

Comment: Well first you need indexes, why on earth would ever create a table with no indexes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Correlated subquerties are a SQl antipattern, they can almost always be replaced by joins and speed up the process.  You should add an order by clause anytime you are selecting top X or the results will not be consistent.

```
SELECT TOP 2 I1.ID, SUM(I2.CurrentStock) AS SimilarItemQuantity  
FROM   Inventory I1
join   Inventory I2 on I1.ProductName = I2.ProductName
GROUP BY I1.ID
ORDER BY I1.ID
```

Comment: +1 - the missing OrderBy is actually a BUG - you do not know which ID's you get back. It may b consistent NOW and break in a month.

Answer (score 0):

Add an index on `Inventory.ProductName` (**key column**) and include the `CurrentStock` and `ID` (**included column**) columns.

```sql
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [Inventory_IDX_ProductName] ON [dbo].[Inventory]
(
  [ProductName] ASC
)
INCLUDE ( [CurrentStock],[ID]) 
WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

You might consider rewriting this as a group by:

```
select top 2 id, sum(CurrentStock)
from Inventory i
group by id, ProductName
order by 2 desc
```

This is presuming that you want the two id's with the largest current stock.

Normally, you use TOP with an order by.

And, as others have mentioned, having an index on (id, ProductName) would help:

```
create index idx_inventory_id_ProductName on inventory(id, ProductName)
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using an aggregate *window* function (`SUM(…) OVER  …`)?

```
SELECT TOP (2)
  ID,
  SUM(CurrentStock) OVER (PARTITION BY ProductName) AS SimilarItemQuantity
FROM Inventory
```

As others have already mentioned, `TOP (n)` doesn't make much sense without an `ORDER BY`. For consistency, use a fixed order in such cases, e.g. `ORDER BY ID`.